# UI Automator java virtual machine Error on mac

Tags: java, android, ui-automation

I'm trying to open UIAutomatorviewer from my SDK tools but I get this error :

```
Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/{user}/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/Users/{user}/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I've checked everything with the appuim-doctor and everything seems OK! (JDK, SDK, JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME, ...)